# How to update the database in Symfony 4?

Tags: database, symfony, symfony4

When I give the following command:

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

the database gets updated, but afterwards this command:

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

keeps saying that the database is *not in sync* (see below screenshot).

What am I missing/doing wrong?

[image: error message]

Comment: Use `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`. You might have some nullable boolean column, there is a "bug" with doctrine when you are using MariaDb.

Comment: If you use MariaDb, make sure you have correct server version in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`, it should be something like `server_version: 'mariadb-10.2.12'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the database type and OS, the test may give some "false negatives", which means that your db is already ok but Doctrine doesn't quite understand. It happened to me in several projects, regardless of Symfony version (which means, Symfony 2,3 and 4).

Besides, in Symfony 4 you can use migrations as explained in [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#migrations-adding-more-fields), that is:

```
bin/console make:migration
```

this command will create a migration file inside `src/Migrations`, but won't touch the db.

To understand what's going on (from Doctrine's oint of view) you may have a look at the migration file: it's a PHP class with two methods (`up()` and `down()`).

The `up()` method will contain the query/queries needed to align the database with your mapping files.

To apply all the pending migrations, run:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Comment: That's true but you should provide a little more context in order to let the OP understand the advantages of this